# change div background on click of button with html and css

Tags: html, css

I want to change the css styling of my div when the mouse hovers over a button. This is my html code:

```
  <div class="container">
<button aria-hidden="false"><span aria-hidden="false" style="color:#b8860b">&#9733</span> CLICK ME! <span aria-hidden="false" style="color:#b8860b">&#9733</span></button> 
  </div>
```

[image: When button isn't clicked]
[image: When button is hovered]

Notice how in the second picture, the div has a border style when the user hovers over the button. How do I get the div to change it's styling when the user hovers over the button?

This is my css file:

```
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #79CEEB;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 50px;
}

.container:hover {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #79CEEB;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    border-style: inset;
}


button {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-color: #444;
    border: 1px;
    border-color: #777;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #abbaab);
}

button:hover {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-color: #444;
    border: 1px;
    border-color: #777;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #8D998D);
}
```

I need this done in only css and html

Comment: I don't see what you want here?

Comment: He wants the div to change styling when a user hovers over the div's child button

Comment: One possible way to cheat your way around selecting a parent: http://jsfiddle.net/6fRUd/19/